# Silverstripe 3.1 Module and Template

Tags: templates, module, silverstripe

I'm making a new Module in Silverstripe, the module is a folder from the root directory.
eg.
module name is portfolio, so directory structure is like -

```
/portfolio
/portfolio/code
/portfolio/templates
```

When I make a page like PortfolioHolderPage.php which extends Page, it renders the page with the PortfolioHolderPage.ss template file, but that's all, it doesn't include the page.ss file from the default theme, any ideas???

Comment: Does `PortfolioHolderPage` controller extends Page_Controller? Is there a `$Layout` in Page.ss? If so, `PortfolioHolderPage.ss` should be in `/portfolio/templates/Layout`

Comment: Yes that's it.  I didn't put it in the /portfolio/templates/Layout folder, so it didn't include page.ss
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making a module, don't forget the folder layout if you still want page.ss to still be included in the template

```
/portfolio
/portfolio/code
/portfolio/templates
/portfolio/templates/Layout
```

Can also put your template in /themes/yourtheme_portfolio/  (yourtheme is the name of your theme), see
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/theme-development
themes/yourtheme_forum/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

A silverstripe module must have a _config directory or a _config.php file to be recognised.

See http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/module-development